# Update multiple columns for multiple rows in one query of SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to set multiple columns for multiple rows in one query, but so far no luck.

Here's how my table looks like

Table: user

[image]

I would like to set 'ext_id' on user_id IN (3,4,5) and also like to set ext_flag = Y and admin_role  = admin on the same rows.

the resulting table looks like follows
[image]

My query looks like this, but I am getting erros due to unfamiliarity to SQL syntax.

```
update user
set ext_flag = 'Y', admin_role = 'admin', ext_id = 
case 
when user_id = 2 then 345
when user_id = 4 then 456
when user_id = 5 then 789
end
```

I am having hard time in SET syntax with multiple columns.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this

```
 update user
 set ext_flag = 'Y', admin_role = 'admin', ext_id = 
 case 
 when user_id = 2 then 345
 when user_id = 4 then 456
 when user_id = 5 then 789
 end
 **WHERE user_id  in (2,4,5)**
```

Comment: Yes sir.SO doesn't allow to mark answer in 5 minutes. Will mark in a minute. :)

Comment: it's nice. but i have doubt it's reduce speed of the application?

Comment: I heard MYSQL has an alternative syntaxe for UPDATE statement like `UPDATE table_name SET(fieldOne,fieldTwo) VALUES (1,2),(3,4) WHERE ...` Is that true ? `Oo`

Comment: And most important, as duly noted with the double-asterisks is the WHERE clause. Pretty important in this case. If you do not include it, all ext_id not mentioned will be marked NULL (experienced just now).

Answer (score 15):

You can also hack the insert operation :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
(2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
(3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
(4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4'),
(5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5'),
(6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
a=VALUES(a),
b=VALUES(b),
c=VALUES(c)
```