# MySQL: update multiple value of a column in single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named `misc_jobs` in which there is a column named `Title` in which Ii have multiple value data for example : Driver , Engineer , Doctor , Teacher , Joker etc.

I want to change some values as Driver, Engneer , Doctor should be converted to Drv , Eng , Doc respectively.

How to update this in MySQL in a single query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091318/update-multiple-columns-for-multiple-rows-in-one-query-of-sql

I think this would help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` like this:

```
UPDATE misc_jobs
SET Title = CASE 
  WHEN client='Driver' THEN 'Drv'
  WHEN client='Engineer' THEN 'Eng'
  WHEN client='Doctor' THEN 'Doc'
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CASE` statement. Something like

```
UPDATE misc_jobs SET Title =  
CASE
WHEN Title = 'Doctor' THEN 'Doc'
WHEN Title = 'Driver' THEN 'Drv'
WHEN Title = 'Engineer' THEN 'Eng'
WHEN Title = 'Teacher' THEN 'Tch'
WHEN Title = 'Joker' THEN 'Jok'
END;
```

Comment: I would use `ELSE Title = Title` as default.

Comment: Yes make sense and so no need of `ELSE` part at all.

Comment: you will need it, while the `set Title` will set it as null otherwise. Either you use Else Title = Title or you add a `while in (...)` with the limitation.