# How can you UPDATE more than 1 column in SQL with one UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'd like to update 2 columns in my database with only one `UPDATE` query

Comment: you must look at other questions asked on this website and search it. After that, if you have problem, you may ask here.

Comment: Yes Indeed !!! I would definitely want to do the same but first let me know what have tried yet? CODE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update multiple columns for multiple rows in one query of SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091318/update-multiple-columns-for-multiple-rows-in-one-query-of-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp